# How we can get the specific pdf page content(text) in Winnovative in c#

Tags: c#

I have a big problem and i need your help.Please send me the solution of above posted question. i want to get the content of pdf generated page in winnovative tool C# library. I can get the number of pages but not get the content(text).So how I can get the specific pdf page content 
Thanks in advance

```
        for (int i = 0; i < winnovative.Document.Pages.Count; i++)
          {
           winnovative.Document.Pages.Count     //return the number of pages
           var page = winnovative.Document.Pages[i];  

            }
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question an hour ago?

Comment: No i am not asking the same question before this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [Winnovative PDF to Text Converter](http://www.winnovative-software.com/PdfToText.aspx) tool to get the text content of a PDF page.